# Joget Business Process Versus Activiti Business Process Management

Tags: business-process-management, activiti

Do any one know from where i can find a comparison between Activiti &  Joget open source BPMs ? containing advantages and disadvantages of each software compared to the other???

BR

Comment: I don't think it exists. There used to be an open source bpm blog with something like that, but it don't exist anymore. What requirments are you looking for?

Comment: thanks for the reply,, i am not searching for specific features,, but i need to find a comparison to decide which tool to use ...